# How to create uninitialised static final variables in Java

Tags: java, variables

The code below produces the compiler error `Variable HEIGHT might not have been initialized` (same goes for `WIDTH`).

How can I declare an uninitialized static final variable like what I'm trying to do below?

```
public static final int HEIGHT, WIDTH;
static{
    try {
        currentImage = new Image("res/images/asteroid_blue.png");
        WIDTH = currentImage.getWidth();
        HEIGHT = currentImage.getHeight();
    }catch (SlickException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to assign a value in catch block too

Comment: Why are the `HEIGHT` and `WIDTH` static and final if `currentImage` is not?

Comment: Are you using `java.awt.Image`? If not, which package are you using the `Image` class from? Is this `JavaFX`?

Comment: @ChetanKinger I expect so, if not `getWidth(null)` is required. But in either cases, what does this matter here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  static {
    Image currentImage = null;
    try {
      currentImage = new Image("res/images/asteroid_blue.png");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // catch exception - do other stuff
    } finally {
      if (currentImage != null) {
        WIDTH = currentImage.getWidth();
        HEIGHT = currentImage.getHeight();
      } else {
        // initialise default values
        WIDTH = 0;
        HEIGHT = 0;
      }
    }
  }
```

Whatever happens (try/catch), you have to assign values to the static variables - therefor, finally should be used.

Comment: You can omit all this burden, as @FastTrail commented, to set the defaults in the `catch`.

Comment: Since the compiler does not know if potentially a variable might have been already initialized, catch is not correct. Compiler: Description
"The final field WIDTH may already have been assigned"

Answer (score 2):

The right way would be to set the values to `null` (in case its an object), but since it's `final` you'll have to do this roundabout:

```
public static final int HEIGHT, WIDTH;
static{
    int w = 0, h = 0;
    try {
        currentImage = new Image("res/images/asteroid_blue.png");
        w = currentImage.getWidth();
        h = currentImage.getHeight();
    }catch (SlickException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    WIDTH = w;
    HEIGHT = h;  
}
```

Comment: You cannot set an `int` value to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but you need to exit the static block by throwing an exception

```
  public static final int HEIGHT, WIDTH;
  static{
   try {
      currentImage = new Image("res/images/asteroid_blue.png");
      WIDTH = currentImage.getWidth();
      HEIGHT = currentImage.getHeight();
  }catch (SlickException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
     throw new RuntimeException("Could not init class.", e);    
 }
```

}

Answer (score -2):

You can't. *final* variables can only be assigned values during initialization,  hence why you're receiving compiler error (the variables will stay null). It's used to ensure consistency.

You can either drop the final keyword or make HEIGHT and WIDTH local variables.

```
currentImage = new Image("res/images/asteroid_blue.png");
final int width= currentImage.getWidth();
final int height = currentImage.getHeight();
```

Comment: And how will the localized variables be accessible outside the `try` block??

Comment: I'm trying to say that you can't use final in his intended situation.

Comment: Didn't know you could do that. I guess I learned something new.